# When type on text fields automatically format like hh:mm from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automatically formatting hh:mm when user types on a text field. Initially it is 00:00 and when user enter first two characters, it should fill minutes part and when type third and fourth characters, it should auto fill hour part. I created a custom script but it seems has some bugs. Can someone help me to solve that. Or If there is some Jquery library, please suggest me. I tried input mask also. But it dosen't have my requirement. Also need the cursor should start from right side.
My HTML is as follows

```js
var num_order = "";
var last_input = "";
var length = 0;

var result_str = "00:00";

$('#price').bind('keydown', function(evt) {
  //alert(String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode));
  length = num_order.length;

  if (length < 4) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 8) {
      num_order = num_order.substring(0, num_order.length - 1);
    } else {
      last_input = String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode);

      if (last_input > 0) {
        num_order = num_order + last_input;
        //alert(num_order);
      } else {

      }
    }
  } else {
    if (evt.keyCode == 8) {
      num_order = num_order.substring(0, num_order.length - 1);
    }
  }
  //alert(num_order);
  var result = update_input(num_order);
  //$("#price").val("");
  $("#price").val(result);
});

var result = update_input(num_order);
//$("#price").val("");
$("#price").val(result);

function update_input(str) {
  length = str.length;
  if (length == 0) {
    result_str = "00:00";
  } else if (length == 1) {
    //alert(str);
    result_str = "00:0" + str;
    //alert(result_str);
  } else if (length == 2) {
    result_str = "00:" + str;
  } else if (length == 3) {
    var first2 = str.substring(0, 2);
    var last1 = str.substring(2, 3);
    result_str = "0" + last1 + ":" + first2;
  } else if (length == 4) {
    var first2 = str.substring(0, 2);
    var last2 = str.substring(2, 4);
    result_str = last2 + ":" + first2;
  }

  //$("#price").val("");
  //$("#price").val(result_str);
  return result_str;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="price" value="00:00" />
```

Comment: Why from right to left? Doesn't makes more sense to first enter HH and than MM ?

Comment: But the requirement is as like that. :(

Answer (score 0):

taking the validation cut off, below example shows how to maintain the 4 digits, starting by the fact that keydown would not be the best place to handle this

[EDIT] however, this might put you back on track (or perhaps not) but it is unlikely to be your final solution, since there is a glitch between keydown and keyup that doesn't look nice

```js
$("#price").val('00:00'); // init

$('#price').bind('keyup',function(evt){
  let last_input= String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode);
  console.log('new char: ' + last_input);
  let str = $('#price').val();
  console.log('before: ' + str); // char was already added
  str = str.replace(/:/, ''); // drop the colon
  console.log('without colon: ' + str);
  //str += last_input;
  if (str.length < 4) {
    str = '0000' + str; // fill zeros on front (cut excess below)
  }
  if (str.length > 4) {
    str = str.substring(str.length - 4, str.length); // drop front
  }
  console.log('about to insert colon: ' + str);
  str = str.substring(0, 2) + ':' + str.substring(2, 4);
  console.log('after: ' + str);
  $("#price").val(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="price" value="00:00" />
```